# Указатели и ссылки

Tags: c++

1. Чем отличается ссылка от указателя?
2. Почему при условиях

   int *p;
   int t=100;

выражения

```
*p=100;
*p=&t;
```

корректны, а

```
*p=t
```

некорректно.

3. Зачем эти сложности вообще?
4. И если можно, как всегда примерчик, раскрывающий хотя бы кусочек глубокой (я так понимаю)идеи ссылок и указателей.

P.S.
Уточняю, прочитав все выше, я понял где то так:

```
struct big{/*some_very_large_struct*/};
struct big baobab;

void doSomething(struct big boom) {
/*do something with boom*/
};

void doSomething1(struct big *boom) {
/*do something with boom*/
};

void doSomething2(struct big& boom) {
/*do something with boom*/
};

int main {
void doSomething(baobab);//эта функция принимает целую копию структуры для работы
void doSomething1(&baobab);//эта функция принимает номер ячейки где искать структуру для работы
void doSomething2(baobab);//эта функция принимает "живую" структуру, но работает с ссылкой на нее
return 0;
};
```

Comment: @cppNoob Метка 'c++' содержит латинскую букву 'c'.

Comment: По вашему P.S.: все действительно так, только то что вы назвали «номер ячейки» обычно называют «адресом в памяти». Таким образом, при вызове doSomething() объект копируется полностью, в doSomethint1() и doSomething2() передается только адрес в памяти. Вызовы этих двух функций одинаково эффективны, и компилятор с большой вероятностью сгенерирует для них одинаковый код.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Что-то Вы, видимо, не то читали… Обычно в книжках крайне понятно излагают…

Так, на пальцах:

---

Вот у Вас есть переменная `int a`. Это такая буковка, с помощью которой компилятор умеет определить, о чём Вы ему говорите. Он знает, что за буковкой `a` кроется значение в памяти, расположенное по какому-то адресу (адрес в памяти — это число). *Ну, Вы же понимаете, что переменная — это такая штука, чтобы удобно по имени обращаться к данным, записанным в определённом участке памяти.*

Так вот, **указатель** — это, тупо, то самое число, тот самый адрес. Т.е. `&a` равно именно в точности адресу в памяти, по которому хранится значение. Чтобы избежать невнятных проблем, тип «указатель на int (или на любой другой тип) — **int***» — это такой совершенно отдельный тип.

Итак есть два волшебных оператора: `*` и `&`. Второй по данной переменной узнаёт её адрес в памяти. Первый по данному адресу (который, как мы помним, хранится в переменной типа int*) возвращает собственно данные, расположенные по этому адресу.

```
int a = 566;
// Завели переменную. Число 566 записалось в память по какому-то адресу

// &a — адрес, по которому записалось число

int *p;
// Переменная типа «указатель на int»
// На самом деле понятно, что все указатели на все типы — одна малина. Это просто
// 32-битные числа. Но C++ строго типизированный язык, потому нельзя непосредственно
// присвоить char* к int*

// Зато можно присвоить int* к int*
p = &a; // Как мы помним, &a возвращает адрес в памяти

int b = *p;
// Теперь в переменной b лежит ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, которое находится по адресу, на который
// указывает p (а как мы знаем, p указыает туда, где лежит значение a)

b == a;
// Это верно

// На данный момент у нас в переменных a и b лежит одно и то же число.

int *p2 = &b;
// Теперь p указывает на a, а p2 — на b.
// a=566, b=566, *p=566, *p2=566

*p2 = 777;
// По адресу, на который указывает p2, положили число 777. Как мы помним, p2
// указывает туда, где лежит значение b. Значит теперь b = 777.

p = &b;
// Теперь оба указателя указывают на одну и ту же ячейку в памяти.

// Ну и так далее
```

---

Про ссылки чуть попозже напишу. Или кто-нибудь другой напишет…

Comment: на основании Вашего опуса провел несколько экспериментов, действительно стало понятнее что почем, спасибо.  
насчет книг, так вот из них я понял что (далее абстракция)китайские палочки это такие деревянные штучки, из прочитанного я догадался что ими можно есть, но так это или нет, и если так то как ими пользоваться я так и не нашел )

Comment: Многие говорят, что Страуструп — это супер-жоская книжка для профессионалов, в которой ничего невозможно понять, пока не съешь пару собак на C++. Так вот, имею честь заявить: это всё полный бред! Читайте Страуструпа. Мужик охрененно объясняет суть.

Comment: не обязательно 32-битные. это зависит от платформы

Comment: "Но C++ строго типизированный язык, потому нельзя непосредственно присвоить char* к int*" - тип тут не просто так. Компилятору надо знать сколько байтов считывать для разыменования и на сколько байт сдвинуться для инкремента указателя. Что бы хранить "тупо адрес" нужно использовать void*.

Answer (score 11):

Ссылки, как и указатели в C++ представляют собой адреса объектов в памяти. Уметь ссылаться на конкретный объект настолько важно, что некоторые языки (Java, например, или семейство .NET) заявляют о том, что это практически единственный способ работать с объектами. На таком уровне абстракции между ссылками и указателями разницы нет.
Разница появляется уровнем ниже: указатель — это значение, объект первого класса, грубо говоря, номер ячейки памяти. С ними можно производить некоторые арифметические операции, сравнивать как числа и т.д. Чтобы, имея указатель (т.е., адрес), получить доступ к объекту по этому адресу, применяется операция **разыменования** (dereference):

```
*p = 100; // указатель p разыменовывается, и в 
          // полученную ячейку памяти записывается число 100
```

Ссылки же, в свою очередь, обладают не семантикой "адресов объектов", а семантикой самих объектов. Можно думать, что ссылка — это указатель, который сам, автоматически, применяет dereference. Из этого есть несколько следствий: например, неизменяемость ссылок. В C++ просто нет синтакисиса присвоения ссылки, любое такое присвоение будет присвоением объекту, на который она указывает.

Теперь о Ваших примерах: `*p=&t;` некорректно (попытка присвоить разыменованному указателю p указатель на число (конкретно, на число t), а не само число), а `*p=t`, как раз, абсолютно корректно (обращаемся по адресу, хранящемуся в указателе, и записываем туда число t).

Если говорить о глубоких мыслях, то, прежде всего, указатели пришли из C и остались тяжёлым наследием. Думаю, некорректная адресация к памяти — самая частая причина падения программ на C++. Ссылки заменить указатели не могут (они не объекты, в отличие от указателей), но здорово упрощают жизнь, когда вам надо передать некоторую структуру весом в пару килобайт параметром в функцию, и копирование замедлит выполнение программы, но Вы не хотите руками возится с указателями. Ссылки имеют такой же синтаксис использования, как и объекты, на которые они ссылаются, и поэтому более-менее взаимозаменяемы.

Чувствую, что написал-то я уже много, а ничего ясного сформулировать не смог :(
Надеюсь, хоть немного понятнее стало

P.S. В C++ есть ещё такая концепция "умные указатели", которые себя ведут как указатели, но проблем с ними меньше. Когда разберётесь со ссылками и обычными указателями, весьма рекомендую их посмотреть.

Comment: все манипуляции в вопросе, в том числе *p=&t взяты из книги.. теперь я думаю вы приблизительно представляете качество информации в ней и почему у меня каша теперь с этими понятиями )

Answer (score 7):

1. Ссылка и указатель на самом деле ничем не отличаются, кроме того, что ссылка инициализируется один раз и её нельзя переоределить + синтаксис другой. Например, если ссылка на класс, то для обращения к членам используется точка . вместо ->
2. Как это *p = t  не корректно? Вполне себе корректно. Если p указывает на какую-нибудь int переменную, то ничто не мешается сделать это (записать значение из t в переменную, на которую p указывает)
3. Какие сложности вы имеете в виду? Зачем указатели?
4. Я так понимаю, что сложность в том, что вы не знаете, зачем указатели нужны? Ну, такой пример:

---

```
struct hello {
    int value1;
    int value2;
};

struct hello instance;

void myfunction(struct hello * p) {
    printf("value1 is %d\n", p->value1);
    p->value2 = 777;
}

int main(void) {
    instance.value1 = 1;
    instance.value2 = 2;

    myfunction(&instance);
    return 0;
}
```

Как видно, мы передаём в функцию указатель на структуру. Не копировать же сами данные через стек. Кроме того, если бы не было указателя, то мы не смогли бы изменить значение value2.

Comment: на мое предложение сделать  *p = t компилятор злобно буркнул что он "can not convert int to int*"

говоря про сложности я говорю про факт существования указателей и ссылок. зачем они вообще нужны? почему нельзя обойтись просто переменными?

Comment: Не может такого быть. Такая ошибка была бы, если бы вы написали p = t (без звёздочки).

Comment: Я бы хотел заметить, что из перечисленных в вопросе выражений два, находящиеся посерединке, не вполне корректны.

Comment: Ну, если перед ними присвоить таки указателю какой-нибудь адрес, то они вполне корректны..

Comment: Я про *p=&t;. Это семантически _некорректно_.

Comment: Ааа... сорри, я не заметил. Конечно же, скорее всего попытка положить в переменную, на которую указывает p, численный адрес памяти, где находится t ошибочна.

Answer (score 7):

> говоря про сложности я говорю про факт существования указателей и ссылок. зачем они вообще нужны? почему нельзя обойтись просто переменными?

Когда я изучал C++, у меня самого точно такой же вопрос появился. Я тогда просто продолжил читать книгу, пока не встретилось использование указателей на практике. Я перечитал эту главу, ещё раз попробовал вникнуть, и получилось понять. Потом, когда я начал работать с графикой, изучал OpenGL и DirectX, я повсюду встречался с этими указателями, причём бывали даже указатели на указатели. Мне это тогда выносило мозг. Потом разобрался и привык. Сейчас мне указатели кажутся чем-то привычным и необходимым.

Если бы не было библиотек, которые используют указатели, думаю, можно было бы без них обойтись. Но от этого бы пострадала производительность, удобство разработки и понятность программы.

Указатели или ссылки используются:

1. Для передачи адреса сложной структуры или объекта, чтобы избежать копирования. Для этого лучше всего по синтаксису подходят константные ссылки.
2. Для возврата нескольких значений из функции. Одного возвращаемого значения, посредством return, из функции может быть недостаточно. Есть два способа вернуть несколько значений: использовать структуру с несколькими полями (что очень неудобно, если эти значения не связаны по смыслу), либо запись по переданному через указатель адресу. Во втором способе можно использовать ссылку, но синтаксически это выглядит как передача параметра, а не возврат. Поэтому указатель в данном случае лучше показывает намерения программиста в коде.
   Использование глобальных переменных я даже не буду называть третьим способом. Это является плохим тоном программирования (почему, узнаешь сам, когда наберёшься опыта), и этого лучше никогда не делать.
3. Ссылки нужны для конструкторов копирования. О них ты узнаешь, когда дойдёшь до классов.
4. Все переменные размещаются на стеке. Они имеют свою область видимости, при выходе из которой они уничтожаются. Для управления жизнью переменной может потребоваться выделить её из динамической памяти при помощи new и сохранить указатель на эту область памяти, чтобы к ней можно было обращаться и удалить её.
5. Указатели используются в такой структуре данных, как списки. О списках ты узнаешь после изучения классов. Они должны быть в любой нормальной книге по C++.

В общем, применений масса. Не думаю, что перечислил хотя бы десятую часть из них.

Answer (score 4):

Ссылка от указателя отличается следующим:

1. Синтаксис ссылки проще (p вместо *p или p.value вместо p->value)
2. Ссылка не может быть «нулевой», то есть ее обязательно нужно чем-то инициализировать.
3. Ссылку нельзя переопределить, то есть она всегда будет указывать на одно и то же место памяти.

См. также [статью про ссылки](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ссылка_(C%2B%2B)) в C++ в википедии.

Во втором вашем вопросе действительно все корректно, как и говорил cy6erGn0m :)

Зачем вообще нужны ссылки — отличный вопрос, по-моему :)

Вообще, конечно, код со ссылками всегда можно переписать на код с указателями. Ссылки ввели в C++ (в C их не было) именно для упрощения синтаксиса.

Еще одно преимущество ссылок — легче модифицировать код. Например, у вас есть функция, принимающая объект некоторого типа A:

```
void f(A a);
```

В какой-то момент становится понятно, что объекты  типа A слишком велики, и копировать их каждый раз при вызове f() слишком дорого. Чтобы не переписывать функцию и места ее вызова на указатели, можно просто изменить объявление функции:

```
void f(A& a);
```

или еще лучше так:

```
void f(const A& a);
```

Comment: а как бы выглядела модификация с использованием указателей? чем она сложнее?

Comment: Если бы мы делали это указателями, в кажом месте, где вызывается функция, нам бы пришлось вручную получать адрес переменной. То есть вместо f(x) мы бы писали f(&x).


Также внутри функции f() все вхождения "a" пришлось бы заменить на "(*a)".

Comment: Таким образом ссылка - это на самом деле указатель, который внешне выглядит как обычная переменная. Если у вас в каком-то месте кода были обычные переменные и вам захотелось использовать преимущества указателей (в частности, быструю передачу в функцию), можно без изменений других частей кода заменить тип переменной на ссылку, и все продолжит работать как раньше.