# Как работают ссылки, указатели, переменные?

Tags: c++, указатели, переменные, ссылки

Переменная - это определенный именованный участок памяти(адрес), в котором хранится значение. Так вот, я не понимаю, как она работает, потому что выводя переменную на экран, мы получаем ее значение. Но допустим мы объявляем ссылку. Неужели мы в качестве `rvalue` подставляем это самое значение? Допустим имя переменной все таки хранит под собой адрес, но тогда зачем мы при объявлении указателя берем адрес этой самой переменной, если она и так содержит адрес? Мне очень интересно узнать, что из себя для компилятора вообще представляет идентификатор - адрес, значение и т. д.

Comment: По моему мнению - ссылка и указатель это одно и тоже, только указатель допускает null, а ссылка нет. И ссылку и указатель есть смысл использовать тогда, когда надо передать переменную в другую процедуру. Поведение ссылки похоже на переменную, её удобнее использовать если локальная переменная превращается в ссылку. Указатель можно использовать как массив, ссылку без преобразования нет. Т.е. ссылка и указатель в x86 это 4 байта. А переменная - занимает столько места сколько требуется даному типу переменной, от 1 байта и более мегабайта.

Comment: При передаче переменной в процедуру в качестве аргумента, происходит копирование всей переменной в стек. При передаче ссылки или указателя передаётся адрес (для стандартного x86 это 4 байта).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%a1

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3424/%d0%a3%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8  тоже хорошее описание с примерами

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо. А что из себя представляет имя переменной? Что там хранится?

Comment: Переменная - это явный метод хранения данных. А ссылка и указатель - это способы неявного обращения к переменным. У переменной есть адрес, его можно получить оператором &. У переменной есть размер, который можно получить sizeof. Но переменной нельзя менять адрес. У глобальных адрес постоянный (за исключением некоторых случаев). Для локальных - плавающий в стеке, но пока жива функция - адрес постоянный. Есть ещё malloc и другие способы выделения в памяти - они позволяют создавать переменные без привязки к имени, просто привязав кусок памяти.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а что тогда происходит, когда мы ссылке присваиваем переменную. Что принимает в себя ссылка?

Comment: Весь вопрос в том, до какой степени детализации и точности вы хотите ответ. Всегда есть какие-то тонкости, исключения и т.п., так, например, лично я давно  не берусь рассказывать такие вещи без предисловия, что это все - очень грубое приближение... Обязательно кто-то вытащит из какого-то темного закутка какой-то пример, в котором все будет не совсем так... Все эти вещи - не более чем упрощение *для человека*. Просто удобнее писать `a=b`, а не придумывать оператор для получения значения в `b` - что потребовалось бы, если бы считать имя переменной адресом... Хватит путаницы с массивами :)

Comment: Есть такая штука в языке C++, как _объект_. Объекты создаются/уничтожаются, занимают некоторое количество байт, имеют время жизни и тип. Иногда объекты имеют _имя_ — некоторый _идентификатор_, который позволяет получить доступ к объекту: прочитать/записать некоторое _значение_ из/в объект(а), или получить _адрес_ объекта. Пример такого идентификатора — это _переменная_. Объект может не иметь имени. Например, если будет создан оператором `new`, в коде нет удобного идентификатора, позволяющего легко обращаться к обекту. Но даже если у объекта нет имени, к нему всё равно можно обратиться

Comment: ... если известен его _адрес_. Такой функционал предоставляют указатели. Разыменовывая указатель, вы обращаетесь к объекту, находящемуся по адресу, на который указывает указатель. Иногда объект может иметь _несколько имён_. Такой функционал предоставляют ссылки. Ссылка  по сути альтернативное имя для некоторого объекта. Как конкретно компиляторы реализуют функционал ссылок/переменных с точки зрения стандарта совершенно не важно. С точки зрения стандарта, ссылка — это не объект, просто альтернативный _способ доступа_ к объекту, альтернативное имя для объекта.

Comment: @wololo, извините, но хотелось бы еще уточнить: когда мы выводим в консоль объект мы получаем его значение. А в случае с ссылкой, точно не значение, может я просто тупой, но я искренне не понимаю что происходит когда мы создаем ссылку на объект, что хранит в себе эта ссылка?

Comment: Вы не можете "вывести ссылку", или получить "значение ссылки", или взять "адрес ссылки". Ссылка — это удобная абстракция уровня исходного кода, которая позволяет назначить некоторому объекту некоторое удобное имя, некоторый идентификатор. Чтобы в исходном коде программы обращаться к объекту по этому идентификатору. После инициализации ссылки, любые манипуляции со ссылкой — это манипуляции с объектом, к которому она намертво привязана. Так же как обычная переменная намертво привязана к объекту, который она обозначает.

Comment: @wololo, получается ссылка с указателем вообще никак не связана?

Comment: С точки зрения языка, никак не связана. Когда вы пишете внутри функции `int var = 0;`, то вы 1) объявляете объект, имеющий автоматический класс памяти, имеющий тип `int`, занимающий `sizeof(int)` байт, имеющий некоторый адрес, 2) а также объявляете удобный идентификатор `var`, с помощью которого вы можете взаимодействовать с объектом. Затем вы пишете `int& ref = var`. Здесь вы только создали альтернативное имя для уже существующего объекта. Любые манипуляции с объектом через `var` или `ref` — это манипуляции с одним и тем же объектом, именами которого являются `var` и `ref`.

Comment: С другой стороны, указатель — это полноценный объект. Так же как и другие объекты, он занимает память, имеет адрес, и т.д. Разве что множество значений указателя немного необычно — это адреса в памяти, _адреса других объектов_. Имейте ввиду, что здесь `int* p = &var;`, переменная `p` — это не сам объект-указатель, а его имя, идентификатор, по которому вы можете получить доступ к объекту. Естественно, вы можете объявить ещё одно имя/идентификатор, ссылающееся на тот же самый объект посредством ссылок: `int*& refp = p;`.

Comment: Но вот если бы вы решили написать _компилятор языка C++_,  то у вас бы возник вопрос, а как собственно можно реализовать _поведение ссылок_ на "уровне железа"? И вот тут-то и можно провести аналогию между ссылками и константными указателями. "Под капотом" ссылки зачастую самые обыкновенные указатели. Но опять же, это всего лишь детали реализации, и далеко не каждую ссылку компилятор реализует через указатели.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ссылки указатели переменные.

Явные переменные. Обычно под переменной понимают запись `int a` (вместо `int` может быть любой другой тип кроме `void`, имеется ввиду тип, который не содержит ссылку или указатель т.к. типы можно переопределять). Это называется *явное* обьявление переменной типа `int`. Такая переменная всегда имеет размерность. Явная переменная может иметь или не иметь адрес. Если компилятор упрощает код - то переменная может попасть в регистр процессора - и быть без адреса (попытка взять адрес в дебагере - покажет что адреса нету). Если компилятор видит что переменная не используется, он может вообще не выдать ни адрес ни регистр и даже не выдать имя. Увидеть что случилось с переменной можно а) в дебаггере б) дизассемблером. в) в map файле. Для глобальных переменных - адрес постоянный (оговорка если компилятор не упростил, если imagtbase постоянный и т п), для локальных - как правило в стеке (если компилятор не упростил). Поведение компилятора может менятся, например без создания ссылки на переменную - у переменной может не быть адреса, а при использовании ссылки - компилятор сделает сборку где у переменной будет адрес. Есть дополнительные подсказки компилятору - их рассматривать не буду. Явная переменная может иметь любой размер от 1 байта до достаточно большого числа байти, которое разрешает сделать компилятор (даже 1 Мб можно).

Неявные переменные. Неявные переменные могут быть получены с помощью malloc, GlobalAlloc и подобных, с помощью вспомагательных библиотек (если создаётся обьект), с помощью ассемблерных операций (как обычные операции, так и SSE MMX и т п), путём прямого назначения адреса. Неявная переменная не может быть обьявлена явно, но их может быть очень много. Неявные переменные к которым есть доступ - могут существовать только в виде ссылки или указателя. Если к адресу нету доступа через ссылку или указатель, то можно считать, что переменная  a) упакована (или хранимая в памяти), её всегда можно получить выполнив опредёленные операции б) потеряная. Потеряные - те которые потерялись в результате ошибок - пропали, и их невозможно найти, именно из таких получается "утечка памяти" (в упрощённом виде).

**Ссылка**. Запись `f(int & b)` или запись `int & b = выражение;` позволяет создать ссылку на обьект. Ссылка не может быть неинициализирована. Тип ссылки должен совпадать с типом обьекта (без & ссылки будет более гибкое преобразование), на который она ссылается и фактически "повторяет" тот объект, который ей присвоен изначально, все операции с новым именем будут иметь те же последствия которые наступили бы при операциях с оригинальным обьектом. Объект начинает обладать новым именем. Гарантировано отличить програмно ссылку от не ссылки - не получится. В ссылку может быть вложен указатель (`int *& a;` имеется ввиду, наоборот - нельзя), двойная ссылка `int & & a` - недопутима. Константная ссылка `int & const a` - недопустима. За "широмой" выражение инициализирует ссылку путём вычисления адреса ссылке "присваивается" адрес. Технически ссылка хранится в памяти и занимает столько же места склько занимает указатель, что иногда условно даёт возможность сократить расход памяти при вызове функции если вместо явной переменной - ссылка. Хотя возможен случай когда компилятор упрощает код выбрасывая из памяти место под ссылку. Обычно ссылка содержит валидный обьект(адрес), но присвоить невалидный тоже можно через невалидную ссылку. При обращении к невалидному обьекту будет или исключение или фатальная ошибка или неопределённое поведение UB. Поэтому если идет преобразование указателя в ссылку желательно проверить валидность адреса. В некоторых языках (делфи) ссылка называется var.  Ссылки имеют поведение очень схожее 99.9% с обычными именоваными переменными, поэтому их иногда используют.

Ссылка на явную переменную может быть записана так `int & b = a;`.

Ссылка на неявную переменную или косвенная ссылка на явную переменную может быть получена a)с указателя на переменную (явную/неявную) через оператор * `int & b = *p;` Но есть исключение. Если переопредёлен оператор  `operator *()`  то будет получена та ссылка которую вернёт оператор. Можно через `malloc` - сначало получаем указатель, потом приводим к нужному типу указателя, потом через *  получаем нужный тип ссылки. Например так `int & z1 = *(int*)malloc*(sizeof(int));` б)через другую ссылку, которая уже задана.

Адрес записанный в ссылке нельзя менять.  а)Манипуляциями с адресами или регистрами позволяют подменить адрес. Но так не делают - это считается UB. б) при неаккуратном использовании памяти ссылка тоже может испортится, если такое произошло - то у вас неправильно написана программа, где-то происходит выход за границы массива, порча стека, порча памяти и т п - нужно аккуратно писать программу что бы такого не произошло.

**Указатель** Указатель - именованная переменная типа указатель. Указатель содержит адрес. Обьект указатель позволяет: а) получать доступ к обьекту, адрес которого взят. б) проверять адрес на 0 (null) или не ноль в) получить адрес обьекта в абсолютном (двоично-десятичном представлении, т.е. как обычное число в случае с линейной памятью)  г) позволяет использовать адрес как типизированый массив, и перемещаться по массиву вперёд (или назад)  д) позволяет менять адрес разными способами, задавать нулевой, задавать значение литералами (цифровое), увеличивать, уменьшать. Указатель может быть как одинарным так и двойным (похож на двумерный массив) и более. Бывает пустой указатель (с нулевым адресом), указатель на явную/неявную переменную, указатель на элемент массива, неинициализированый указатель может сожержать "мусор" его использование может вызвать ошибки или UB - перед использованием такому указателю нужно присвоить значение. Обычно указатель задаётся выражением `int *p;` звёздочкой, но есть ещё несколько более сложных форм записи (для методов и методов класса, и ещё есть случаи). Указатель можно перепутаь с оператором `*()`. Указатель может быть как константным (дополнительно поставить модификатор const), так и таким который можно менять в процессе.

Есть указатель, а есть оператор `тип operator *()`. Указатель задаётся в секции обьявления типа, во всех других случаях - это оператор разименования указателя (т.е. преобразование в значение или ссылку). Обычно этот оператор не переопределяют, но некоторые программисты ради запутывания кода могут переопределить его.

Указатель не даёт доступ к обьекту на который он указывает напрямую. Для того что бы получить доступ к обьекту, нужно использовать один из 3-х операторов `*` `->` `[]` . Если выражение слева - ссылка - то `*` `[]` дают значение или ссылку. Если выражение слева - не ссылка, то происходит копирование всего значения в тот обьект, который слева. Эти три оператора работают для обьекта указатель, для других обьектов нет, но могут работать для отдельных обьектов, если данные операторы для них заданы.

Оператор * `operator *()` (без операндов, умножение - с операндами, получение сслыки - без) - это оператор получения значения или ссылки из указателя. Пример использования `*p`, `(*p).field` (для классов). Принято использовать для не массивов и не классов. Но не запрещено использование для даных случаев.

Оператор стрелка `operator ->()` - получает доступ к полям Пример использования `p->fied`. Оператор доступен только для структур и классов.

Оператор взятия элемента массива `operator [](тип index)` - позволяет расскрывать указатель как ссылку на элемент масса. Приемр `p[0]`, `p[0].field`. Обычно этот оператор используется с ссылками на массив и с массивами, но нулевой элемент будет аналогичен как * (если операторы не переопределены). Для массива - можно получить длинну массива, для указателя - нет. Неаккуратное ображение с этим оператором может приводить к сбоям, зато ввиду отсутствия проверки на выхода за пределы масиива - повышается быстродействие.

Обычно первые два оператора не принято менять, но все три оператора могут быть изменены для запутывания кода, или для создания "кастомного" указателя. Оператор `[]` обычно переопределяют, когда хотят сделать "улучшеный" или "виртуальный" массив.

Так как указатель приходится часто преобразовывать в значение (реже в ссылку), то иногда указатели и ссылки люди путают между собой.

Размер ссылки, размер указателя. Физически и указатель и ссылка имеют одинаковый размер. Поэтому подмена внутри функции аргумента ссылкой или указателем - может приводить к сокращению расхода оперативной памяти. Но встроеное `sizeof()` покажет разный размер, для ссылки - будет всегда размер обьекта на который ссылается ссылка, а для указателя - будет размер адреса. Для обычного линейного x86 с 32-битным режимом адресации размер будет равнятся 4 байта, для x64 - 8 байт. Но адрес может быть другого размера от 1 байт (для некоторых микроконтроллеров), 2 байта (16-битный режим), бывают сегмент-офсетные "двойные" адреса (метка far). Проэтому если вы пишите под кросс-платформу или под нестандартнуюю платформу - то надо учитывать что размер адреса может быть другим. И в некоторых случаях можно создать два указателя с разной размерностью адреса (при написании драйвера или загрузчика например). И опять же, если компилятор сократит ссылку или указатель - то физически указатель/ссыка могут быть без адреса (но адрес будет хранится или в регистре ЦП или две "переменных" будут хранится по одному адресу).

Пример идеинтичного кода с указателем и ссылкой

```html
По сути, с точки зрения ассемблера 
- ссылка и указаель - это почти одно и то же. 
Отличие только в том, что с точки зрения с++ 
это разные обьекты с которыми совсем по разному 
нужно работать, хоть и по функциональности они похожи. 
Если не использовать все возможности указателя 
- то ассемблерный код будет идеинтичным. Следующие примеры сформируют одинаковый ассемблерный код 
(в 99% случаев).<code>

    void SetupA_ptr(char * a){// код с указателем этого метода будет
      *a = 'x';            // идеинтичный коду следующего метода
      }                    // Но тут можно проверить ссылку на null

    void SetupA_ref(char & a){// код с ссылкой
      a = 'x'; // А тут нельзя сделать проверку на null 
      }        // (т.к. при преобразованиях может возникнуть UB)
    //----------
    char z;
    SetupA_ptr(&z); // И даже вызов тут код вызова будет одинаковым
    SetupA_ref(z);  // И вызов тут
</code>
```

Пример проброса адреса

```html
Если выражение слева готово принять ссылку - происходит передача ссылки. Если выражение слева не готово принять ссылку, то происходит копирование данных. lvalue - означает left-value - преобразование по значению слева. Например (скомпилировано в старом BCC 5.0):

int a0 = 1;    /*  mov [ebp-180h],1; */ 
// Делаем ссылку на a0
int & a1 = a0; /*  lea edx, [ebp-180h]; mov [ebp-184h],edx; */ 
// Берём адрес с a1, точнее получаем указатель на a0, на обьект на который ссылается ссылка
int * a2 = &a1 /*  mov ecx, [ebp-184h]; mov [ebp-188h],ecx; */
// Ниже делаем ссылку по полученому адресу, в итоге на обьект a0
int & a3 = *a2 /*  mov eax, [ebp-188h]; mov [ebp-18Ch],eax; */
// Берём адрес обьекта из ссылки a3, т.е. фактически адрес a0
int * a4 = &a3;/*  mov edx, [ebp-18Ch]; mov [ebp-190h],edx; */
printf("%X ",a1); /*Вывод: 1*/
printf("%X ",a2); /*Вывод: 18FDD0 адрес a0*/
printf("%X ",a3); /*Вывод: 1*/
printf("%X ",a4); /*Вывод: 18FDD0 адрес a0*/
                     
   Но если мы ссылку или звездочка-указатель присваиваем в int - то он поменяет свой адрес.

int b0 = 1;
int * b1 =  &b0;  // Тут адрес b0
int b2 = *b1;    // Тут мы теряем ссылку, b2 не умеет хранить адрес.
int * b3 =  &b2; // А тут будет адрес b2
int & b4 = b0;  // Тут адрес b0
int   b5 = b4;  // Тут мы теряем ссылку, b5 не умеет хранить адрес.
int * b6 =  &b5; // Тут адрес b5 

Но если мы пишем

int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int * pa = &a;
int * pb = &b;
*pa = *pb; // тут в а скопируется значение b, присваивание ссылки не  будет
int & c = *pb; // тут будет скопирован адрес b, т.к. инициализация
// Менять ссылку ещё раз - запрещено,  int& - слева запрещён.
с = a; // Скопирует значение а, 1  в переменную b.

Аналогичо, если мы передаём аргумент в функцию 
f1(int arg1) - то `arg1` получает копию переменной и 
для arg1 резервируется отдельное место для хранения, 
изменения в arg1 не повлияют на значение переменной в вызвавшей функции, 
а если мы передаём аргумент в функцию 
f2(int & arg2) - то arg2 сохранит адрес переменной, 
а если передали ссылку - то адрес ссылки, 
если передали *p  (от `int * p`) - то сохранит адрес записаный в p. 
И изменения в arg2 коснуться той переменной, 
на которую создана ссылка изначально.
```

Упрощенный пример "умного" массива

```html
class MyArray {
    int * source;
    int max_index;
    int noValue; // Если адрес не верный.
   public:               
  void Init(int * src, int maxidx) {
       source = src;
       max_index = maxidx;        
       }

   int& operator[](int index) {
      if ((index < 0)||(index >= max_index)) return noValue; 
          // Вернём что-нибудь, 
          //но можно a) вызвать исключение
          //можно    б) вызвать printf и вывести ошибку на экран
      return source[index];   
      // Будет передана ссылка на элемент, 
      // Поэтому при изменении результата, который вернул оператор []
      // будет меняться оригинальный массив.
      // если убрать & - то получится "readonly" массив.
      // Ссылка позволяет аккуратно сделать "проброс"
      }             
   }

  MyArray arr;
  int array[10];
  arr.Init(array,10);
  arr[1] = 10;// сохранится
  arr[20] = 20; // не сохранится, сбоя не будет

  P.S. В STL есть хорошая реализация массива std::array
```

Полный map-файл может дать ответы, какие адреса каким переменным ссылкам и указателям дал компилятор. Если конечно уровень детализации позволяет это увидеть. Так же дизассемблированый код покажет что компилятор сделал с вашими переменными и ссылками. Использование переменных и ссылок позволяет оптимизировать код и более гибко управлять памятью.

Comment: Ух ты, выражаю вам свою благодарность)

Comment: К сожалению, есть неточности. Например, вы тиражируете расхожий штамп, что  если определено int *p, то *p выдает ссылку на p, хотя она выдает lvalue типа int.
Подробности на en.SO, там же и ссылки на стандарт: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388510/generally-is-dereference-pointer-expression-results-a-reference-type/48388647#48388647

Comment: @gbd я дополнил ответ примерами, возможно вместо слова ссылка нужно писать lvalue, там и правда два варианта поведения. Для ссылки слева - одно. Для не ссылки - другое.

Comment: @nick_n_a, извините за возможно тупой вопрос, но если фактически ссылка - разыменованный указатель на переменную и инициализируется адресом переменной, при чем при инициализации мы не берём ее адрес, то почему нельзя было сделать так, чтобы при инициализации указателя, в качестве rvalue стоял просто идентификатор переменной, без операции взятия адреса?

Comment: @n1kzzz наверное для того что бы не было путаницы. С++ к сожелению выдаст ошибку. Такие правила преобразований.  Но если у вас стоит задача так делать, то создав кастомный класс, и обьявив implicit operator (int&) вы будете ловить адрес автоматом.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я на всякий случай переспрошу, чтобы избежать недопониманий в дальнейшем (извиняюсь за это). Утверждение: "ссылка это фактически разыменнованый указатель на переменную и содержит в себе адрес на эту переменную" - будет верно?

Comment: @n1kzzz, `ссылка это фактически разыменнованый указатель` Это ошибка. Указатель является _объектом_, занимает некоторое количество памяти (_storage_) и имеет адрес. Ссылка **не объект**, ссылка не занимает память и вы не можете взять адрес ссылки.

Comment: @wololo но мне ведь удалось получить адрес ссылки, получилось его сохранить когда хочу, и получилось его потерять когда хочу. И если мы ссылку пробросим далее - то адрес не потеряется.

Comment: Какая языковая конструкция позволяет получить адрес ссылки? Как получить размер ссылки в байтах? Как объявить массив ссылок?

Comment: Оператор взятия адреса.  `int a0 = 1;   int & a1 = a0; int * a2 = &a1  int & a3 = *a2  int * a4 = &a3; printf("%X ",a2);  printf("%X ",a4);` вот будет два одинаковых адреса. Размер ссылки - получить нельзя. Массив ссылок - нельзя - это не предусмотрено языком, можно ссылку на массив. Ссылку можно пробросить в другую функцию которая принимает ссылку, адрес сохранится, и значение по этому адресу при пробросе будет корректно изменено в перво-переменной, которая породила ссылку.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду этот участок `int * a2 = &a1`, то в `a2` хранится адрес объекта, _на который ссылается ссылка_. Это `&a1` не адрес ссылки. Можно получить адрес _указателя_ `&a2`, и мы получим адрес того участка в памяти, где хранится указатель. Как точно также получить адрес самой ссылки, если она объект? `Размер ссылки - получить нельзя. Массив ссылок - нельзя` Тогда почему можно размер указателя и массив указателей, если "ссылка это фактически разыменнованый указатель"?

Comment: Ок, мы получаем не адрес ссылки, а адрес обьекта на который ссылается ссылка. При присвоении ссылка2 = ссылка1 проиходит копирование этого адреса. С точки зрения ассемблера и ссылка и указатель - это участок памяти который хранит адрес, поэтому визуально кажется что просходит просто присвоение.

Comment: `С точки зрения ассемблера и ссылка и указатель - это участок памяти который хранит адрес` В том-то и дело, что вы смотрите со стороны ассемблера. Я пытаюсь донести ту мысль, что с точки зрения _стандарта языка_ ссылка совершенна **не** похожа на указатель. Когда ссылка инициализируется, никаких присвоений адресов не происходит. Просто ссылка становится некоторым идентификатором, через который можно манипулировать объектом. В этом ссылка _очень похожа_ на обычную не ссылочную переменную. Просто альтернативное имя, через которое можно воздействовать на объект.

Comment: Ваши объяснения в ответе, безусловно имеют смысл. Компиляторам как-то нужно реализовать поведение ссылок, описываемое стандартом языка. И сделать ссылки через указатели — типичный подход. Но это не требование стандарта языка. Стандарту всё равно, как будут имплементированы ссылки. Концептуально ссылки существенно отличаются от обычных объектов (а указатель это тоже объект).

Comment: Текста много, однако по содержанию - полнейшая каша, демонстрирующая незнание основ.

Answer (score 3):

Не следует ставить этот вопрос в такой формулировке и вот почему: *компилятор С++ очень хорошо оптимизирует программу*.

Это значит, что допущение о том, что переменная - "именованный участок памяти" в общем случае, верно не всегда ( иногда это регистр, иногда переменная вовсе оказывается выброшена за ненадобностью)

Также неверно, что при вызове функции всегда будет происходить копирование параметров в стек - они могут и через регистр передаться, а еще, все тело вызываемой функции компилятор может заинлайнить, если захочет.

"ссылка" **не является указателем который не может быть null**. При компиляции с ней происходят совсем другие вещи (в какой-то момент компилятор перестает отличать внутри себя ссылку и саму переменную, если может это сделать).

А что будет при векторизации при помощи SIMD? А у вас несколько переменных попадут в один 128-бит или 256-бит (или 512-бит, если у вас крутой проц) регистр.

В связи с этим нужно помнить про правило as-if - компилятор выдает машинный код, который будет вести себя эквивалентно тому, что понаписано в программе, но вот как он это сделает - никто гарантий не дает.

Закладываться на то, что компилятор выдаст в ответ на какой-то код на C++ какой-то конкретный ассемблер можно было году так в 1990м.

Comment: Минусующие приглашаются в комментарии с аргументами.

Comment: Я не минусовал. Почитал ответы на похожие вопросы - наверно надо где-то час два посидеть, что бы оговорить все тонкости указателей переменных и ссылок и расписать все возможные ветви поведения. Если чесно - ни один из ответов на этот вопрос мне на so не понравился. Думаю вы согласитесь с тем что ваш ответ не полный.

Comment: Потому что нормальным ответом будет "смотри в стандарт".

Comment: Тогда надо ответ писать с ссылкой на страндарт.

Comment: @nick_n_a - проблема в том, что этих выводов и примеров в стандарте нет, это результат наблюдений над работой компилятора, которые любой желающий может повторить, путем написания тестовых программ и анализа ассемблера.